# C++: How to insert node at a certain position in a linked list?

Tags: c++, linked-list

Need to insert a new node that contains the given data value, such that the new node occupies the offset indicated. Any nodes that were already in the list at that offset and beyond are shifted down by one.It should have the same effect as appending and no effect if it is beyond the end of the list.

```
void LinkedList::InsertData(int offset, int data){
  shared_ptr<node> curr(top_ptr_);
  shared_ptr<node> temp(new node);
  temp->data = data;
  temp->next = shared_ptr<node>(NULL);

  if(offset == 0) {
    temp->next = top_ptr_;
    top_ptr_ = temp;
  }
  offset--;
  while(offset-- && curr->next!=NULL)  {
    curr = curr->next;
  }
  temp->next = curr->next;
  curr->next = temp;
}
```

Comment: have you tried this:   `while(--offset && curr->next!=NULL) `  and delete `offset--` in front of the loop.

Comment: `curr->next!=NULL` is almost always a bad idea in a linked list because it requires a bunch of extra testing to ensure that `curr` is valid before you can test `curr->next`. You should rework the logic so that it tests for `curr != NULL` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are close.  Since you are handling `offset==0` specially, you need to move your `while` loop inside of an `else` block, eg:

```cpp
void LinkedList::InsertData(int offset, int data) {
  if (offset < 0)
    return; // or throw...

  shared_ptr<node> temp(new node);
  temp->data = data;

  if (offset == 0) {
    temp->next = top_ptr_;
    top_ptr_ = temp;
  }
  else {
    shared_ptr<node> curr = top_ptr_;
    while ((--offset > 0) && curr->next) {
      curr = curr->next;
    }
    temp->next = curr->next;
    curr->next = temp;
  }
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/QgGr85)

However, `InsertData()` can be simplified by eliminating the `if (offset == 0)` block altogether, eg:

```cpp
void LinkedList::InsertData(int offset, int data) {
  if (offset < 0)
    return; // or throw...

  shared_ptr<node> temp(new node);
  temp->data = data;

  shared_ptr<node> *curr = &top_ptr_;

  while ((offset-- > 0) && *curr)
    curr = &((*curr)->next);

  temp->next = *curr;
  *curr = temp;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/V7WVug)